# How can i get 0 in front of any number?

Tags: vb.net, string, format

I would like to append 0 before a number if it is single digit. For example it should be 01,02,03... 09, 10, 11, ...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
Dim yourNumber as Int32 = 5
yourNumber.ToString("D2") '= "05"
```

Comment: +1 From the docs about the D specifier "This format is supported for integral types only. The number is converted to a string of decimal digits (0-9), prefixed by a minus sign if the number is negative. The precision specifier indicates the minimum number of digits desired in the resulting string. If required, the number is padded with zeros to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision specifier." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720653(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: gives me InvalidCastException to IFormatProvider :/

Comment: I used yourNumber.ToString("00"). That also worked for Integer variables.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
myNum.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0");
```

Comment: You need to set the width as 2 to prefix with zero

Answer (score 4):

Try the following...

```
Dim varNumber As Integer = 3
Dim number As String = String.Format("{0:0#}", varNumber)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1st result for Google: vb.net string format zero. http://idunno.org/archive/2004/14/01/122.aspx

Comment: @mcandre: I can't visit that link here at work. What am I missing?

Comment: It's a guide to VB.net string formatting, including padding and different format types.

Answer (score 1):

Old school method from VB6, still works:

```
Dim yourNumber as Long = 5 
Format(yourNumber, "00") ' = "05" '
```

... just for old time's sake :). Better to use [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102808/how-can-i-get-0-infront-of-any-number/3102912#3102912).

Answer (score -3):

```
if(number < 10){
  number = Int32.Parse("0" + number.ToString());
}
```

I guess that was some c# going on :) but you should get the idea.

Comment: That's going to return an Int32, not a padded string.

Comment: hmph...Int32.Parse would strip out the leading 0, no?

Comment: Ops! Sorry about that ^^ Wasn't thinking straight