# Visual Basic: Simple Counter with leading Zero

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a simple counter that increases when the button is clicked.
What I would like is when the counter is clicked it displays "01", "02" etc.

I can create it already with "1", "2", but I would like to have a leading zero.

I have searched and found I can do this by converting the label to a string, but I cant seem to get the value to count?

If I change "count.text = counter" to "count.text = cot" it will display "01", but wont count. I'm guessing this is due to the fact its only displaying what is currently in the string but not increasing the value?

If I could get any guidance that would be great!

Many thanks!

```
Dim counter As Integer = 1
Dim cot As String = String.Format("{0:00}", counter)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    counter = cot + 1
    count.Text = counter
End Sub
```

Comment: `1.ToString("00")` should work like `counter.ToString("00")` I will search for the fitting duplicate. Found it.. So basically you only need `count.Text =counter.ToString("00")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get 0 in front of any number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102808/how-can-i-get-0-in-front-of-any-number)

Comment: You could use the [String.PadLeft Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1), like `count.Text = counter.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0"c)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't update your formatted number properly. It's only initialized a single time.

To *increment* the counter, use `counter += 1` or `counter = counter + 1` first. This will add 1 to the current value of the integer variable. Then modify the text of your `Label` by calling that formatting code again: `count.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", counter)`.

Comment: its VB, not strict on the type. BTW I complied code on LinqPad for double-checking.

Comment: @Baljeetsingh Oh sorry, I thought it was vb.net.

Comment: Its VB.net Only Dear

Comment: @Baljeetsingh I've updated my answer. When I was coding in VB.net for eight years as a professional software developer, I set up my Visual Studio to display an error message in such cases.

Comment: Thank you @André Reichelt; so looks like I was along the right lines with it!
Just needed to move the string within the button click as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

PadLeft is the key.

```
Dim number as Integer = 12
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0")). ' prints 12
number = 2
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0")). ' prints 02
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

it converts the string into an integer. increments the number, converts it back into a string and then checks for a leading 0, if not found it adds it.

I will let you convert it into your button click for practise, as it should help you have a good understanding of the conversion between types :)

```
Sub string_counter()

Dim string_counter As String

    string_counter = "00"
    
    For x = 0 To 10
    
        Debug.Print string_counter
        
        string_counter = Int(string_counter) + 1
        string_counter = Str(string_counter)
    
        If Left(Trim(string_counter), 1) <> "0" Then
            string_counter = "0" + Trim(string_counter)
        End If
        
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Lewis Morris, thank you for the code change! 
Going to try this as a different way of getting the result to increase my understanding!